# Generatate layout (XAML) programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

How can I generate layout (XAML) programmatically?

Let say I have some kind of loop. And after each I want to generate this with the values I got:

```
                <Grid Height="150" Name="grid1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Height="150" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" Grid.Column="1" Source="/Ilm;component/Images/testicon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <TextBlock Height="51" Name="textBlock1" Text="Paris" Margin="12,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="40" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="40" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,75,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="19°C" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                </Grid>
```

Comment: You want to add new rows to it or generate the entire thing?

Comment: I want to generate the entire thing... as many as needed.

Comment: Ok, check out my answer below. I updated it to add a grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a new row to the grid, you will need to add a new row definition and then add the new controls.  It will be similiar to the following logic:

```
rowNumber = 0; // Set the current row that you are adding 
grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

Image img = new Image();
img.Height = 150;
img.Name = "image1";
img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
img.Width = 200;
img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
// Set your image properties
img.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
img.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
grid1.Children.Add(img);

TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
// Set your text block properties
tb1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
tb1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
grid1.Children.Add(tb1);

TextBlock tb2 = new TextBlock();
// Set your text block properties
tb2.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
tb2.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
grid1.Children.Add(tb2);
```

You will need to put the properties that you want to set where I have the comment and also provided the correct row number (zero based).

To add the entire thing...

```
Grid grid1 = new Grid();
grid1.Height = 150;
grid1.Name = "grid1";
parentControl.Children.Add(grid1); // Note: parentControl is whatever control you are added this to
grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = 200});

// From here insert the code for adding a row that is provided above
```

And that's it.  You'll just need to fill in the properties I haven't provided.  Remember that your variable `parentControl` will be different.  You haven't provided what control you are adding these into, so it is unclear what that would be.

Comment: When I'm trying to add the grid to "parentControl" it says "The parameter is incorrect." and nothing more valuable to fix the error... than you for your long answer of course.. maybe I should look for ItemsControl instaed.. because this is too complicated for me...

Comment: Ok, after 1 hour I got it... I made your code work for my project. You're the boss, besos!!!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to place all the code in the code-behind as [Hexxagonal as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10517495/9664).

Another option, and more conventional, is to use an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx). This will allow a cleaner separation of responsibilities by leaving the visual layout in the XAML rather than code-behind.

Comment: Yeah definitely.  I should have mentioned that his programmatically method wouldn't be the best.

Comment: No doubt. I just wanted to throw that out there in case the OP wasn't aware of the ItemsControl.